# Texmaker just exits with no message

Tags: texmaker

I am running Ubuntu 18.04. Installed texmaker today and it worked for a while then stopped, complaining that a certain file was missing. I did some steps including installing tex-live-full and now when I start texmaker it just exits with no message. If I run it from the command line, the status code is zero. I have tried apt-get purge and reinstall with no improvement. Is there a log file somewhere?

When I say "which texmaker" it points to a file that does exist.

Running it from the GUI, it also just exits with no message.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Given that it is an Ubuntu issue, you did the best approach, as it was possible that after an update, TeXmaker was trying to access a library that was still not loaded in memory, so rebooting fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Rebooted; now it works with and doesn't exit.